# Writing my first app for Android and I have a few questions

Tags: android, database, postgresql, sqlite

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this.

I am a developer with 17 years of code experience.  I have some code that I've written over the past few years in my spare time and it's heavily dependent on a postgres database.  I want to port this program into a smart phone app and have a ton of questions but the most glaring questions are:

1. I can organize the app to use a local database on the smart phone but I am wondering if it would be better to keep the large database data on a server with only the users access credentials stored in the phone app.
2. I am just an independent developer, Is it possible to set up a server to host this database at my house serve up it's contents in response to requests from the apps on phones?  Are there any web hosting solutions that are affordable that also allow a developer to customize the database easily?
3. Is the sqlite database that comes with an Android robust enough to handle multiple tables some of which holding thousands of rows of data?

I could invest in a small server and set the database up on it.. and even configure it to use my existing network connections but I am not sure this is the best approach.

ANY suggestions or advice you can offer on this topic will be appreciated a great deal.  I really want to do this right from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a baas solution. Most of them are easy to scale and easy to use. Some are also free to use. Then you can easy update your database and you don't have to put the data into your app. Also you don't have to make server maintences by yourself.

But you can also use a database on any server and catch the data from your phone.
I tried sqlite with phpliteadmin on rasppi and it worked very well.
But I can't give any information with thousands rows of data inside such a database.

Comment: Never heard of Baas and searches returned Billing As a Service.. is that what you mean?

Comment: Are there reasonable places that have servers available to host custom databases that also allow the installation of a jar of REST services to filter access to the database?

Comment: A Baas solution means Backend as a Service. [Wikipedia Backend as a Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_backend_as_a_service) So you don't have to think about the backend of your app. I'm using Parse. So i would tell you a bit of the concept. Parse will shut down it's service in 2017, so you shouldn't use it anymore. I think other services are equivalent to it. You just create an account. Then you can create databases with custom columns.

Comment: You can access the database with one of the native sdk's. You can access your database by anomynous logins or with user registration. Most support also facebook login. Also there are a lots of other features like user management. A open source solution would be [BAASBOX](http://www.baasbox.com/) Some products also support cloud coding.

Comment: I've looked into some of these services and it seems that the cost for these is going to be astronomical if you have app downloads in the thousands or hundreds of thousands and I fully expect to have that kind of a userbase.  I don't mind maintaining a server I just don't know if it's possible to set a server up at my house using my existing network access.

Comment: I certainly don't want to be paying a third party every time one of my users  instigates a query on a database.

Comment: Ok I understand what u mean. Sorry for that. Theoretical is possible to setup a server at your home. But do you think it can handle all this requests? I don't know much about servers so I can't help u anymore :)

Comment: I can get a server and set it up for about $600, that will at least allow me to get my initial prototype up and running .. perhaps if that goes as well as I expect it to go I can acquire funding to set up an actual server farm with a t-1 line.  It's just depressing to think that there is no way for an independent developer to write their own apps and service them without sending every bit of profit off to someone else.

Comment: Then BAASBOX would be your solution I think. You can install it for free on your server and it's open source.

Answer (score 0):

1. Whether it makes sense to keep the data on a server, so that it is not tied to a single mobile device, is something you have to device yourself.
2. A server in your house is probably not very reliable.

   Recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow.
3. Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).
   But thousands of rows is a trivial amount for any database.

Comment: It was in reading the documentation .. not the version you linked but other documentation about using a database in an app that caused me to start rethinking my strategy.  Things like do not initialize the database on the main stream and database initialization causing apps to hang were the culprits for scaring me off. I was really looking not for recommendations but for peeps who have experience with including a database in an app that doesn't just hold user information.  Currently the database has 10 tables.  a couple of the tables would hold thousands of rows.